# How to split and rebuild a string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, replace, split

I have the following code:

```
var input = "RE1467R31294998782";
var arr = input.split("");
```

and after executing it I get:

`R,E,1,4,6,7,R,3,1,2,9,4,9,9,8,7,8,2`

after that goes the following code:

```
arr2[0] = arr[0]+arr[1]; 
arr2[1] = arr[2]+arr[3];
arr2[2] = arr[4]+arr[5]; 
arr2[3] = arr[6]+arr[7];
arr2[4] = arr[8]+arr[9]; 
arr2[5] = arr[10]+arr[11];
arr2[6] = arr[12]+arr[13]; 
arr2[7] = arr[14]+arr[15];
arr2[8] = arr[16]+arr[17];
```

and the result is:

`[RE,14,67,R3,12,94,99,87,82]`

the end result should be the following:

`RE-1467-R3-1294-99-8782`

So, I would like to add a `-` every time the string changes from `alphanumeric or >94` to `numeric and <95`.

But how do I do that? Any ideas?

Thanks for helping me out.

Edit: The string is always 18 chars or 11 chars long.

More examples:

`1ZA2666W6831071503 to 1ZA2-66-6W-6831071503`

`1Z80A3109303081604 to 1Z-80-A3-109303081604`

`1Z80A3109603089504 to 1Z-80-A3-10-96-0308-95-04`

Comment: Is the string always the same number of characters?

Comment: @WhiteHat, the string has always 18 characters or 11 characters.

Comment: Is adding a `-` after 2 then after 4, then after 2 again and so forth also okay (except in the end)?

Comment: Maybe add another example or two, this would help, I think @maraca is on to something...

Comment: @maraca, no, sorry, the string could also be 1ZA2666W6831071503 so the end result should be 1ZA2-66-6W-6831071503.

Comment: why does the - go after number 2? 1ZA2-66, why does the - go here, why isn't it getting extended? example 1ZA266..

Comment: Your examples are inconsistent with your criteria.

Comment: I think I get it, you are always looking at character pairs and never at single letters?

Comment: I gues this is true @maraca, this is why the arr2 array is so important here..

Comment: I got not idea about the requirements.

Comment: @renokl2014, PLEASE REWRITE YOUR POST! SO IT IS 100% CLEAR WHAT YOU WANT!

Comment: @eugensunic He cannot, his requirements are dynamic :)

Comment: 'So, I would like to add a "-" every time the string changes from alphanumeric or >94 to numeric and <95.' -- this makes no sense.

Comment: @maraca, yes you get it. :)

Comment: @renokl2014 I would get it, if there was a `-` after the `96` in the last example.

Comment: @maraca i edited my last example into: 1Z80A3109603089504 to 1Z-80-A3-10-96-0308-95-04, so if this is your result, you get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could somewhat cleanly do it like this

```js
var inputStr = 'RE1467R31294998782';
var splitRegex = /(\w{2})/g;
var pieces = inputStr.match(splitRegex);
var finalStr = [];
var prevDuet = '';

if (pieces && pieces.length > 0) {
    pieces.forEach(function(currentDuet) {
        if (!prevDuet) {
            finalStr.push(currentDuet);
        } else if (currentDuet > 94) {
            finalStr.push('-' + currentDuet);
        } else if ((isNaN(prevDuet) && !isNaN(currentDuet)) ||
                   (!isNaN(prevDuet) && isNaN(currentDuet))) {
            finalStr.push('-' + currentDuet);
        } else if (prevDuet > 94) {
            finalStr.push('-' + currentDuet);
        } else {
            finalStr.push(currentDuet);
        }
        prevDuet = currentDuet;
    });
}

alert(finalStr.join(''));
```

Answer (score 2):

And now for the ugliest answer possible:

```
var input = "RE1467R31294998782";
var arr = input.split(""), arr2 = [];
for(var i=0;i<Math.floor(input.length/2);i++){
    arr2[i] = arr[i*2]+arr[(i*2)+1];
}

var rebuilt = '';
for (var i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    rebuilt += arr2[i]+(i < arr2.length - 1 && (isUnit(arr2[i]) || isUnit(arr2[i + 1])))?'-':'';
}

function isUnit(part) {
    return String(part).match(/[A-Za-z]/g) || Number(part) > 94;
}

alert(rebuilt);
```

Even uglier but hopefully satisfies the condition in the other examples:

```
var input = "RE1467R31294998782";
var arr = input.split("");
var arr2 = [];
arr2[0] = arr[0]+arr[1]; 
arr2[1] = arr[2]+arr[3];
arr2[2] = arr[4]+arr[5]; 
arr2[3] = arr[6]+arr[7];
arr2[4] = arr[8]+arr[9]; 
arr2[5] = arr[10]+arr[11];
arr2[6] = arr[12]+arr[13]; 
arr2[7] = arr[14]+arr[15];
arr2[8] = arr[16]+arr[17];

var rebuilt = '';

for (var i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    var part = arr2[i],
        nextPart = arr2[i + 1];

    rebuilt += part;

    if (i < arr2.length - 1 && ((isAlpha(part) && !isAlpha(nextPart)) || (!isAlpha(part) &&  isAlpha(nextPart)) || isBigNum(part) || isBigNum(nextPart)))
        rebuilt += '-';
}

function isAlpha(part) {
    return String(part).match(/[A-Za-z]/g);
}

function isBigNum(part) {
    return Number(part) > 94;
}

alert(rebuilt);
```

(Sorry for lousy formatting to editor of my above code.)

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't what the OP wants.

Comment: @dustmouse thanks. it is almost my solution. If i try your code with 1ZA2666W6831071503 it goes to 1Z-A2-66-6W-6831071503 but it should be 1ZA2-66-6W-6831071503.

Comment: Check out the second (somehow even uglier) solution.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately after the correction this alternative doesn't look nice at all, but works correctly:

```
var m = 0; // 0 = init, -1 = alpha-num, 1 = numeric < 95, 2 = numeric > 94
"RE1467R31295998782".replace(/[A-Z0-9]{2}/g, function(a) {
  if (isNaN(a)) {
    if (m == 1 || m == 2)
      a = '-' + a;
    m = -1;
  } else {
    if (parseInt(a) > 94) {
      if (m != 0)
        a = '-' + a;
      m = 2;
    } else {
      if (m == 2 || m == -1)
        a = '-' + a;
      m = 1;
    }
  }
  return a;
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tqvpskf9/3/)