# How to create substrings, replacing substrings?

Tags: javascript, regex, pdf

With the following code I turn a string:

**`1Z3245799938735257`**

into:

**`1Z›324579š99›38735257`**

But now, I want to split the areas, between "`›`" and "`š`" and between "`›`" and the end of that string, into pairs.

So that the sub result is:

**`1Z›32,45,79š99›38,73,52,57`**

Now I want to change the pairs into `String.fromCharCode(pair+32)`

So that the sub result is:

**`1Z›@,M,oš99›F,i,T,Y`**

Replacing the `","` with `""`
So that the ultimate result is

**`1Z›@Moš99›FiTY`**

How can I do this?

```
var chars = new Array();
chars["00"] = " "; chars["01"] = "!"; chars["02"] = "“"; chars["03"] = "#"; chars["04"] = "$"; 
chars["05"] = "%"; chars["06"] = "&"; chars["07"] = "’"; chars["08"] = "("; chars["09"] = ")";
chars["10"] = "*"; chars["11"] = "+"; chars["12"] = ","; chars["13"] = "-"; chars["14"] = ".";
chars["15"] = "/"; chars["16"] = "0"; chars["17"] = "1"; chars["18"] = "2"; chars["19"] = "3";
chars["20"] = "4"; chars["21"] = "5"; chars["22"] = "6"; chars["23"] = "7"; chars["24"] = "8";
chars["25"] = "9"; chars["26"] = ":"; chars["27"] = ";"; chars["28"] = "<"; chars["29"] = "=";
chars["30"] = ">"; chars["31"] = "?"; chars["32"] = "@"; chars["33"] = "A"; chars["34"] = "B";
chars["35"] = "C"; chars["36"] = "D"; chars["37"] = "E"; chars["38"] = "F"; chars["39"] = "G";
chars["40"] = "H"; chars["41"] = "I"; chars["42"] = "J"; chars["43"] = "K"; chars["44"] = "L";
chars["45"] = "M"; chars["46"] = "N"; chars["47"] = "O"; chars["48"] = "P"; chars["49"] = "Q";
chars["50"] = "R"; chars["51"] = "S"; chars["52"] = "T"; chars["53"] = "U"; chars["54"] = "V";
chars["55"] = "W"; chars["56"] = "X"; chars["57"] = "Y"; chars["58"] = "Z"; chars["59"] = "[";
chars["60"] = "\\"; chars["61"] = "]"; chars["62"] = "^"; chars["63"] = "_"; chars["64"] = "`";
chars["65"] = "a"; chars["66"] = "b"; chars["67"] = "c"; chars["68"] = "d"; chars["69"] = "e";
chars["70"] = "f"; chars["71"] = "g"; chars["72"] = "h"; chars["73"] = "i"; chars["74"] = "j";
chars["75"] = "k"; chars["76"] = "l"; chars["77"] = "m"; chars["78"] = "n"; chars["79"] = "o"; 
chars["80"] = "p"; chars["81"] = "q"; chars["82"] = "r"; chars["83"] = "s"; chars["84"] = "t";
chars["85"] = "u"; chars["86"] = "v"; chars["87"] = "w"; chars["88"] = "x"; chars["89"] = "y";
chars["90"] = "z"; chars["91"] = "{"; chars["92"] = "|"; chars["93"] = "}"; chars["94"] = "~";

var charsv = new Array();
charsv[" "] = 128; charsv["!"] = 01; charsv['"'] = 02; charsv["#"] = 03; charsv["$"] = 04; 
charsv["%"] = 05; charsv["&"] = 06; charsv["’"] = 07; charsv["("] = 08; charsv[")"] = 09; 
charsv["*"] = 10; charsv["+"] = 11; charsv[","] = 12; charsv["-"] = 13; charsv["."] = 14; 
charsv["/"] = 15; charsv["0"] = 16; charsv["1"] = 17; charsv["2"] = 18; charsv["3"] = 19;
charsv["4"] = 20; charsv["5"] = 21; charsv["6"] = 22; charsv["7"] = 23; charsv["8"] = 24; 
charsv["9"] = 25; charsv[":"] = 26; charsv[";"] = 27; charsv["<"] = 28; charsv["="] = 29; 
charsv[">"] = 30; charsv["?"] = 31; charsv["@"] = 32; charsv["A"] = 33; charsv["B"] = 34; 
charsv["C"] = 35; charsv["D"] = 36; charsv["E"] = 37; charsv["F"] = 38; charsv["G"] = 39;
charsv["H"] = 40; charsv["I"] = 41; charsv["J"] = 42; charsv["K"] = 43; charsv["L"] = 44;
charsv["M"] = 45; charsv["N"] = 46; charsv["O"] = 47; charsv["P"] = 48; charsv["Q"] = 49; 
charsv["R"] = 50; charsv["S"] = 51; charsv["T"] = 52; charsv["U"] = 53; charsv["V"] = 54; 
charsv["W"] = 55; charsv["X"] = 56; charsv["Y"] = 57; charsv["Z"] = 58; charsv["["] = 59; 
charsv["\\"] = 60; charsv["]"] = 61; charsv["^"] = 62; charsv["_"] = 63; charsv["`"] = 64; 
charsv["a"] = 65; charsv["b"] = 66; charsv["c"] = 67; charsv["d"] = 68; charsv["e"] = 69;
charsv["f"] = 70; charsv["g"] = 71; charsv["h"] = 72; charsv["i"] = 73; charsv["j"] = 74; 
charsv["k"] = 75; charsv["l"] = 76; charsv["m"] = 77; charsv["n"] = 78; charsv["o"] = 79; 
charsv["p"] = 80; charsv["q"] = 81; charsv["r"] = 82; charsv["s"] = 83; charsv["t"] = 84; 
charsv["u"] = 85; charsv["v"] = 86; charsv["w"] = 87; charsv["x"] = 88; charsv["y"] = 89; 
charsv["z"] = 90; charsv["{"] = 91; charsv["|"] = 92; charsv["}"] = 93; charsv["~"] = 94; 
charsv["š"] = 104; charsv["›"] = 105; charsv["œ"] = 106;

var x = this.getField("S1").valueAsString;
var out = this.getField("B1");

var m = 0;
var transformedString = x.replace(/[A-Z0-9]{2}/g, function(a) {
  if (isNaN(a)) {
    if (m > 0)
      a = 'š' + a;
    m = -1;
  } else {
    if (parseInt(a) > 94) {
      if (m != 0)
        a = 'š' + a;
      m = 2;
    } else {
      a = String.fromCharCode(parseInt(a) + 32);
      if (m == 2 || m == -1)
        a = '›' + a;
      m = 1;
    }
  }
  return a;
});

transformedString = transformedString;

out.value = transformedString;
```

thank you so far.

But now comes the last few steps:

first: get the values from every single char from the array "charsv".

second: sum of char-values: (104*1)+(char-value1*1)+(char-value2*2)+(char-value3*3) and so on.

third: get the modulo of the sum. (sum of char-values % 103).

fourth: get the char of this value from the array "chars". if " ", replace with "€".

fifth: add "š" at the beginning from "transformedString" add the char from fourth and an "œ" at the end of "transformedString".

Comment: @nnnnnn because i want to use the script in a .pdf-File.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4tqp4gnh/) (adaptation of my answer to [How to split and rebuild a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31776693/how-to-split-and-rebuild-a-string))

```
var m = 0; // 0 = init, -1 = alpha-num, 1 = numeric < 95, 2 = numeric > 94
var transformedString = "1Z3245799938735257".replace(/[A-Z0-9]{2}/g, function(a) {
  if (isNaN(a)) {
    if (m > 0)
      a = 'š' + a;
    m = -1;
  } else {
    if (parseInt(a) > 94) {
      if (m != 0)
        a = 'š' + a;
      m = 2;
    } else {
      a = String.fromCharCode(parseInt(a) + 32); // the only additional line
      if (m == 2 || m == -1)
        a = '>' + a;
      m = 1;
    }
  }
  return a;
});
```

Comment: thanks for that jsfiddle looks perfect, but if i copy it to my pdf-file to test it, the field that has to be filled with 1Z›@Moš99›FiTY shows [object Field], where is the problem?

Comment: @renokl2014 it probably means that an object was used where a string was expected, so then js implicitly converts it to a string and you end up with something like that.

Comment: @renokl2014 can't tell from your code, did you assign what is returned by the replace to out.value? are you using this later? do you pass `out` somewhere where you should use out.value? ... I never modified pdf with js.

Comment: thanks a lot. after the last update, your solution works fine for me.

Comment: i have edited my question a last time. so now it shows the complete task. please can you help me out again?

Comment: @renokl2014 this sounds kind of crazy, are you creating a hash? Anyways you can either split the string or use substr to extract the 1 letter strings by iterating over the string and converting them to numbers by just putting it in the array (should use objects for associative arrays, everything stays the same except init is {} ), if the value is > 100 you add the previous sum if any reset the counter for the multiplier and start building the sum, you can just modulo each time for simplicity. When finished add characters at front and end.

Answer (score 2):

```
function convert(x) {
    return x.replace(/›[^š]*/g, function (y) {
        var s = "›";
        for (var i = 1; i < y.length; i += 2) {
            var code = parseInt(y.substring(i, i + 2));
            s += String.fromCharCode(code + 32);
        }
        return s;
    });
}

var result = convert("1Z›324579š99›38735257"); // 1Z›@Moš99›FiTY
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt, might be a little much.

```
function transform(str) {
  return str.replace(/›[^š]+/g, function(m) {
    m = m.slice(1).replace(/../g, function(c) {
      return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(c) + 32)
    })
    return '›' + m
  });
}

var result = transform('1Z›324579š99›38735257') // 1Z›@Moš99›FiTY
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a regex like this:

```
/(\d{2})(?=\d+)/g
```

With substitution `$1,`.

[[Regex Demo]](https://regex101.com/r/kQ7dL9/1)

Comment: The criteria for converting is not that there is at least one digit following (what does the `+` help there?), it is that the pair consists of two digits and is < 95. It becomes clearer if you look at the question I've linked.